# pandas cross matching events in time

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas `DataFrames` full of `Timestamps`. I want to cross match these events to within 5 days of each other. If I was to cross match df1 on to df2 I would like e.g. a list (in the generic sense) of size len(df1) where each element contains a list of the indices of elements in df1 which lie within the specified time limit of the corresponding element in df2. I would also like a similar structure that instead of indices, contains the number of days between events.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date_1': ['2016-10-10', '2016-10-11', '2016-10-18', '2016-10-29']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date_2': ['2016-10-10', '2016-10-05', '2016-10-27', '2016-10-01']})
```

output:

```
matched_indices = [[0,1], [0], [3], []]
matched_deltas  = [[0,1], [5], [2], []]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're going to include code (a good thing) at least paste code you've actually run.

Comment: Good luck hehe:-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen that was pretty silly. I had already corrected your deliberate mistake! Thanks for your initial help anyways

Comment: @piRSquared point taken feel free to run the code now. Now, can you please remove your down vote? I think this is an interesting question, if initially ill posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = np.abs(df1.date_1.values[:,None]-df2.date_2.values)/np.timedelta64(60*60*24, 's')
newdf=pd.DataFrame(s)
matched_deltas = 
newdf.mask(newdf>5).stack().groupby(level=1).apply(list).reindex(df1.index).tolist()
matched_deltas

matched_indices =newdf.mask(newdf>5).stack().reset_index().groupby('level_1')['level_0'].apply(list).reindex(df1.index).tolist()
matched_indices
```

Output:

```
[[0.0, 1.0], [5.0], [2.0], nan]
[[0, 1], [0], [3], nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to iterate through all of the rows of df2, and find the differences with the dates in df1.

```
matched_indices = []
matched_deltas = []
# iterate throug hthe rows of df2
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    # s is a series that stores the difference between the two dates, the index is the same as df1's
    s = abs((df1['date_1'] - row['date_2']).dt.days)
    # keep only the differences that are less than 5
    s = s.where(s<=5).dropna()
    # add the indices to matched_index 
    matched_indices.append(list(s.index.values))
    # add the values to matched_deltas
    matched_deltas.append(list(s.values.astype(int)))
```

I hope it helped!